# How to restrict the user did not enter more than two digits after decimal point?

Tags: android, decimal, restriction

I have edittext in listview. I want to restrict the user if they enter more than two digits after the decimal point. Now it allowing n number of numbers. How to restrict the user did not enter more than two numbers after decimal point without using pattern?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Answer (score 3):

We can use a regular expression ( regex ) as follows:

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
            if(!matcher.matches())
                return "";
            return null;
        }

    }
```

To use it do:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5,2)});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to do it?". What is your problem with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

It might be late but i am posting my solution hope it will works for someone

in Your Text Watcher Method  afterTextChanged do this .

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if(mEditText.getText().toString().contains(".")){
                    String temp[] =  mEditText.getText().toString().split("\\.");
                    if(temp.length>1) {
                        if (temp[1].length() > 3) {
                            int length = mEditText.getText().length();
                            mEditText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Here in (temp[1].length() > 3)  3 is the limit of digits after "." you can replace it with your limit

Comment: that is actually pretty nice +1
But why split("\\.") why not just split(".")

Comment: Java is Bad while Spliting "." thats why we use \\. to accomplish it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and in the [afterTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) method use a regular expression to match the required text and delete the extra numbers are they are entered.