# Android: Restricting textfield to one decimal point

Tags: java, android, regex

How to restrict an EditText Field to only one decimal point. Let's say the user should enter only one digit/number after the `(.)[decimal].`

User enters : 1.92 `[Its invalid]`
User enters : 1.9 `[Its Valid]`

Below is the regular expression i am using.

```
mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
```

I am having problems with the decimals, user if enter `23.1` its fine, but the same user can enter `2.31`.

How can i restrict user to enter only one number/digit after decimal.

Comment: This question covers quite the same issue with the decimal restriction. Including solutions with `RegEx` and the `InputFilter Interface`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Answer (score 3):

How about using a regular expression for that..

```
public class DecimalDigitsFilter implements InputFilter {

Pattern pattern;

public DecimalDigitsFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
    pattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned destination, int destinationStart, int destinationEnd) {

    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(destination);       
    if(!matcher.matches())
        return "";
    return null;
   }
}
```

And then call it as..

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsFilter(5,1)}); //5 before point and 1 after point.Change it as your need
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to the textView and use it's methods to prevent typing after dot more then one number.