# How to add a keyup event in android in c#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, keylistener

I am trying to add a key listener for a edittext object. 
this is my .axml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/amountTextBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this is how i get the object
    EditText textbox=FindViewById(Resource.Id.amountTextBox);

I am trying to change the text when they press a key so it is formatted as a decimal number i.e. if they input 5 the outcome will be 0.05.

I tried using textbox.KeyPress but this only gets called when the back key or done key are pressed.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I am developing for android in c# therefore I need a solution that works with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWathcer(){
      @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

});
```

Comment: is that in c#? 
the AddTextChangedListener takes as an argument ITextWatcher in my case so I can't create an instance of it.

Comment: No it's perl, in your case ITextWatcher is an interface create a class that implements it and pass it to addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do it in code, try adding this to your EditText object:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't have to outcome that i want. with this if the existing text it 0.00 and i press 5 the outcome would be 0.005 whereas i want it to be 0.05.

Comment: OK - you could implement your own InputFilter as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Comment: that would be very useful if it was c# but unfortunately some of the methods just don't exist in c# such as Pattern.compile