# Is there a keypad widget for Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio, android-keypad

I'm working on a checkbook app, and I'd like to use a small widget like a TimePickerDialog or DatePickerDialog but one that acts like a keypad so the user can enter an account or transaction balance. I know I can use an EditText but I would like to be able to implement a keypad.

Does Android have any predefined UI elements to support this? I have tried to find some, but without luck. I did find an interesting article to implement my own using a GridLayout, but wondered if someone was aware of any Android classes that could already do this.

The GridLayout method: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in the XML for your EditText, you'll get a keypad. If you decide that you need a more specialized keyboard, there's a very good tutorial [here](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to come up with something more unique, almost like it's own activity but an edit text will do just fine. I'm going to bookmark that tutorial though incase I use it in the future. 

I found this other question (for anyone who reads this and might want to use a keypad) that explains how to use a filter for EditTexts. They're especially useful for a checkbook app, because all dollar amounts will be limited to two decimal places:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. Read this tutorial: [Creating an Input Method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)
2. Clone this repo: [LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. That actually was what I was looking for, but I decided for this project an EditText was the simplest way to accomplish what I wanted to do. I'm definitely going to hold on to this for later.