# Android : How to prevent users from entering numbers with more than 3 decimal places

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, validation

I've got an EditText in my app, in which I don't want users to enter numbers with more than 3 decimal places. This is because in the SQL server database that is going to store that data I send from the phone has this data type :

```
numeric(15, 3)
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

I've already set these values, but they would only help me partially:

```
android:maxLength="15"
android:lines="1"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

## Edit

This is what I tried:

```
            mQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String str = mQuantityEditText.getText().toString();
            DecimalFormat format=(DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
            char sep=symbols.getDecimalSeparator();


            int indexOFdec =  str.indexOf(sep);         

            if(indexOFdec >=0) {
               if(str.substring(indexOFdec,str.length()-1).length() >3)
               {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(),str.substring(0, str.length()-1));                    
               }
            }
         }
        @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }
        @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                      


         }      
     });
```

It worked because it only allows 3 decimal places, but I'm still not sure how to control the max number of digits to fit in the `numeric(15,3)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just sending the number rounded to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Comment: Why not implement onTextChange listener and perform a regex?

Comment: @biegleux If let users enter numbers with too many decimal places, when I show the data or when I edit the data locally on the phone I end up with the numbers displayed in what it looks like scientific notation

Comment: Than why not just round the number before displaying it?

Comment: I know, it's just that didn't want to go through all the pain of having to format the data every time I need to display it and then round it when I need to send it to the server.

Comment: Still you have to validate on server against malicious input.

Comment: I would use a textwatcher and dynamically change the max length as soon as the user inputs a decimal separator.

Comment: @njzk2 How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

> For the limited number of character, you can add a Android API filter :

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

> For the numeric editText, there is also a obscur solution :

```
DigitsKeyListener MyDigitKeyListener = new DigitsKeyListener(true, true); 
editEntryView.setKeyListener( MyDigitKeyListener );
```

Comment: How is that obscure? (Also it does not limit the size of the input)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RestrictDecimal implements InputFilter {

Pattern mPattern;

public RestrictDecimal(int beforePoint,int afterPoint) {
    mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (beforePoint-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (afterPoint-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.mat`enter code here`cher(dest);       
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }

}

// Set for edit Text
editEntryView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new RestrictDecimal(15,3)});
```

Comment: please format your code and explain why your solution is an answer to the question