# QR Code Generation in Android where the input field accept only float values?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to generate QR Code in Android where the input field accepts ONLY float values with 2 decimcal points only (precision values) e.g.: 10.50,800.75,1000.25

Comment: so what do you need, a generator or a specialized input field?

Comment: Yes..Specialized input field as mentioned above accepts only float values with 2 decimal points.

Comment: you did not answer my question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit Decimal Places in Android EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext)

Comment: if so, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Comment: thanks!!!! The link was helpful.