# Limit after dot in EditText

Tags: java, android

I have EditText with numberDecimal. I want to set limit max 2 number after dot, something like 20.99
I can not use a maxLenght.
EditText take from user string, so how can i set this limit ?
**I can not use InputFiler**

Comment: One of the ways is to use regex + TextWatcher

Comment: Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5357455/614807

Comment: but i can not use a inputFilter

Comment: Why you can not use inputFilter?