# How can I force user to enter a value in EditText in prescribed format

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can someone please help me? How I can force user to enter the `numberDecimal` in `EditText` field in XX.XX format(Eg.56.75).

I used max length attribute to restrict max length to 5.

Comment: You can add "." when the enter the third character as number using textwatcher

Comment: @Developer Please tell me how I can do that ??

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext

Comment: I think having two `EditText`  will be a good approach for this from design as well as coding perspective. Quite similar to EditText for CreditCard numbers .

Comment: @SivaPrasad please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go the easiest way

```
<EditText
   //.....
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" /> // set inputformat
```

You can use `InputFilter` if you need to make sure there are 2 digits before `.` and after.

Try this under onCreate

```
youreditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter()});
```

this is just a class for this

**EDIT:** 
Had to rewrite the pattern as it seems that matcher matches the input starting with the first character and checks each one so you need to add a lot of optional parts in the patterns so that it passes each check that is being made. Now it doesn't allow 222 as it did in your case

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start) {
            String destTxt = dest.toString();
            String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
            if (!resultingTxt.matches("^\\d(\\d(\\.\\d{0,2})?)?")) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but I could only enter either XX or .XX (Eg : either 67 or .67) It is only allowing two digits or decimal and two digits after it

Comment: I edited the regex and checked it , now it matches 21.21 for example

Comment: `mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{" + digitsBeforeZero + "}\\.[0-9]{" + digitsAfterZero + "}");`  I tried this, this time it is not letting anything to enter

Comment: "[0-9]{digitsBeforeZero}\\.[0-9]{digitsAfterZero}"    I edited it this way it matches, check

Comment: When I am using that `digitsBeforeZero` directly without string concatenation, IDE showing error "number expected here"

Comment: that's weird, just hard code 2 to try then "[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}", as you always expect 2 and 2 and then you can look into why it doesn't allow it, as we declared these variables as ints

Comment: In this way, this is not letting anything to enter. It is not taking at all

Comment: `[0-9]{0,2}+((\.[0-9]{0,1})?)||(\.)?`  This is working and taking values in `xx.xx`, `x.xx`, `.xx` formats. But it is also taking values in `xxx` format too. Once I type 3 numbers in a row, after that 3 numbers it is not letting me to enter dot or any other number. And user should not able to enter `xxx` format.

Comment: @SivaPrasad wow,man! It wasn't easy but after an hour in the studio it finally does the trick. Sorry, for my late response! I edited my ancwer, please check. Had to create a sample app for this case

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
        TextWatcher t1;
        EditText e;
        t1=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(s.length()==3 && !s.toString().contains("."))
                {
                    e.removeTextChangedListener(t1);
                    e.setText(s.subSequence(0,1)+"."+s.charAt(2));
                    e.addTextChangedListener(t1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        e.addTextChangedListener(t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
      String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(s.toString());
      edittext.setText(yourFormattedString);
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
exitText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(charSequence.length() == 2){
                exitText.setText("");
                exitText.setText(charSequence+".");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have decimal number format, you can use this in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

To limit the number of digits, you might need to use `InputFilter` mentioned in other answers or here: [Limit Decimal Places in Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

This following code is also working :

**Inside OnCreateView :**

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2,2)});
```

**Java Class :**

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {


    final int maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint ;
    final int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint ;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeDecimal,int digitsAfterDecimal ){
        maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint = digitsBeforeDecimal;
        maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint = digitsAfterDecimal;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
        builder.replace(dstart, dend, source
                .subSequence(start, end).toString());
        if (!builder.toString().matches(
                "(([1-9]{1})([0-9]{0," + (maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint - 1) + "})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0," + maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint + "})?"

        )) {
            if (source.length() == 0)
                return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
            return "";
        }

        return null;

    }


}
```