# Android edittext - do not allow decimal separator alone

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, decimal

I have an Edittext, where I want to allow only numbers and decimal numbers (max 2 decimals after separator e.g. 125.50).

I implemented a filter for this:

```
 final EditText  field1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field1);
 field1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });

    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        final int maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint=5;
        final int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint=2;

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
            builder.replace(dstart, dend, source
                    .subSequence(start, end).toString());
            if (!builder.toString().matches(
                    "(([0-9]{1})([0-9]{0,"+(maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint-1)+"})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,"+maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint+"})?"

            )) {
                if(source.length()==0)
                    return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
                return "";
            }

            return null;

        }
    };
```

**This is working fine**, but the problem is, that if user inserts decimal separator ALONE, I've got java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."

In my **ontextChanged** I tried this:

```
 if(field1.getText().toString().equals("[.]")){field1.setText(0);}
```

also this

```
if(field1.getText().toString().equals(".")){field1.setText(0);}
```

but did not work.

How can I restrict the decimal separator alone, but allow it with the numbers?

Comment: try this `^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$` regex it allows numbers with an optional decimal point followed by digits. A digit in the range 1-9 followed by zero or more other digits then optionally followed by a decimal point followed by at least 1 digit:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this:

```
if(field1.getText().toString().equals(".")){field1.setText(0);}
```

is your exact code, then for sure it failed because `0` is not a string, it's an integer considered to be a resource id.  
So first try this:

```
if(field1.getText().toString().equals(".")){field1.setText("0");}
```

If it fails again then consider that a `NumberFormatException` can be resolved by `try/catch` like this:

```
double value = 0.0;
try {
    value = Double.parseDouble(field1.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    field1.setText("0");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: perfect, the .setText("0") fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For References, you can use this link if you want to use InputFilter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368816/10396176

For other references, if you want using want to try using textWatcher:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684661/10396176