# How do I set the number of decimals in BigDecimal class in Java?

Tags: java, android

```
double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(etDepositAmount.getText().toString());
                    BigDecimal depositAmountSafe = BigDecimal.valueOf(depositAmount);
                    BigDecimal userBalance = BigDecimal.valueOf(user.getBalance());

                    int comparisonResult = depositAmountSafe.compareTo(userBalance);

                    if (comparisonResult > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(contex, R.string.INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Deposit deposit = createDeposit();
```

In the above piece of code, I should be able to create a deposit if only the entered sum for the amount is less or equal to the user's balance.
But for example if the user's balance is 62921.0, I am able to enter 62921.0000000000000001 and get the deposit created. How do I set the number of decimals?
And if not, how can I enforce that the user can only enter a maximum number of digits as decimals. For example a maximum of 3 digits to the right of a a decimal point(eg. x.123 and not x.1234) for an EditText.

Comment: Your first two lines are a mistake. Once you convert the `String` to a `double` you've lost precision. `BigDecimal depositAmountSafe = new BigDecimal(etDepositAmount.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))* constructor, instead of the *valueOf* method.

Additionally, you should be parsing the amount directly from the *String* value, as opposed to using a *Double#parseDouble* call.  It will preserve the precision.

```java
BigDecimal depositAmountSafe = new BigDecimal(etDepositAmount.getText().toString());
BigDecimal userBalance = new BigDecimal(user.getBalance());

int comparisonResult = depositAmountSafe.compareTo(userBalance);

if (comparisonResult > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(contex, R.string.INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
Deposit deposit = createDeposit();
```

This will cause your *if-conditional* check of *comparisonResult* to match.

Consider the following example.

```java
BigDecimal depositAmountSafe = new BigDecimal("62921.0000000000000001");
BigDecimal userBalance = new BigDecimal("62921.0");

int comparisonResult = depositAmountSafe.compareTo(userBalance);

if (comparisonResult > 0) {
    System.out.println("insufficient balance");
    return;
}
System.out.println("create deposit");
```

Output

```
insufficient balance
```

In regard to setting the decimal places, here is a relevant question and answer.
*[StackOverflow – Limit Decimal Places in Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368816/17758716)*.